# Overloaded operator C++: Object = Object * Object

Tags: c++, object, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm having trouble multiplying objects using the overloaded * operator

In the class I have the operator defined as:

```
const Matrix operator*(Matrix& B);
```

The implementation is

```
const Matrix Matrix::operator* (Matrix& B){
   Matrix r = Matrix(B.M,B.N);

   for(int i = 0; i < r.M; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < r.N; j++){
        r.data[i*N+j] = (*this)(i,j) * (int)B(i,j);
       }
   }
   return r;
}
```

When I call

```
 Matrix C = A * B
```

I will get the expected result, however calling

```
C = C * C
```

Results in an error.

I'm guessing it's to with the calling object C but I'm not sure what to do!

EDIT:

My assignment operator. Matrix R is a deep copy.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix& B){
Matrix r(M,N);

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        r.data[i*N+j] = B(i,j);                                 
    }
}
return r;
```

}

Comment: What kind of error? Compile-time or Run-time? If it's run-time, does it crash, or does it just give incorrect results?

Comment: I'd recomend changing the function signature to `Matrix Matrix::operator* (Matrix const& B) const`.

Comment: Only square matricies can be multiplied on itself

Comment: It is square my friend. Assume C is 5x5.

Comment: @Billy Jake O'Connor: What did you do to the copy-assignment operator of your `Matrix` class? You error is there, not in what you posted.

Comment: I will post that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are storing your data in a variable called "data" (which is an int[] on the heap) and you haven't overridden your assignment operator to copy the values from the object being copied into the current member variable "data". So, the default assignment operator will copy the "data" pointer for you, which in your case is from a temporary value that will be out of scope after the assignment. Your destructor will most likely delete the "data" variable you are now pointing to because the temporary goes out of scope.

You have defined your own copy constructor to establish the "data" variable on the heap. The first example you have where Matrix C = A * B will use that copy constructor, which works.

The second example uses the default assignment operator, which will only copy the data pointer from the temporary value returned from the operation. Thus, you basically have no value that data is pointing to.

You have to define an assignment operator to make this work.

Here are suggested functions to go along with your copy constructor:

```
void Matrix::swap(Matrix& other)
{
   std::swap(M, other.M);
   std::swap(N, other.N);
   std::swap(data, other.data);
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator= (Matrix matrix)
{
   swap(matrix);
   return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator* (const Matrix& B)
{
   Matrix r = Matrix(B.M,B.N);

   for(int i = 0; i < r.M; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < r.N; j++){
        r.data[i*N+j] = (*this)(i,j) * (int)B(i,j);
       }
   }
   return r;
}
```

This works well because the copy constructor will be used for "matrix" in assignment operator (operator=). Then, the swap function will trade the "data" array with the temporary copy of Matrix. Therefore, you will copy the appropriate "data" from the operation*'s temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "calling object C".

The first version

```
Matrix C = A * B;
```

uses *constructor(s)* or class `Matrix` to initialize new object `C`.

The second version

```
C = C * C;
```

uses *assignment* operator of class `Matrix` to assign new value to an existing object `C`.

You managed to screw up the assignment operator declaration/implementation somehow (which you don't show in the code you posted), which is why the second version does not compile.

There are problems with your `operator *` declaration as well. Even if you want to have it as class member, a more meaningful way to declare it would be

```
Matrix Matrix::operator* (const Matrix& B) const {
  ...
```

Note how `const` qualifiers are placed.

**EDIT:** So, here's your problem. Your assignment operator is completely broken.

Firstly, you declared your assignment operator as

```
Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix& B)
```

This operator cannot accept temporary objects on the right-hand side because you failed to declare the parameter as `const`. Non-const references cannot be bound to temporary objects. And in `C = C * C` the right-hand side of assignment is actually a temporary object produced by `*`operator.

Redeclare your assignment operator as

```
Matrix &Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& B)
```

Note, it accepts a `const` reference and returns a reference.

Secondly, your assignment operator is supposed to assign to `*this`, not to some standalone temporary object. And it is supposed to return a reference to `*this`. In other words, the implementation should be something along the lines of

```
Matrix &Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& B){

  // Resize `*this` to match the size of `B`

  for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        this->data[i*N+j] = B(i,j);                                 
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: If the method is const, how would it create a new matrix? Or modify an existing one?

Comment: @Billy Jake O'Connor: This is not "assignment operator". What you posted is a *copy constructor*. It has absolutely nothing to do with assignment operator. Your problem is in *assignment operator*. Do you understand the difference between *copy constructor* and *assignment operator*??? Assignment operator is called as `operator =`. What did you do to it?

Comment: @Smac89: What do you see as a problem with creating new matrix in a `const` method??? `const` method only prevents you from modifying `*this` and nothing else. The OP does not modify (and does not need to modify) `*this` in `operator *`, so it is perfectly logical to declare the method `const`.

Comment: Okay, I'm completely new to C++ and I've crammed it all in. I thought the copy constructor would work in place of the assignment operator. Why won't the = operator simply copy the values of C * C into C? Or do I need explicitly tell it how to handle it?

Comment: @Billy Jake O'Connor: Did you declare your own `operator =` or not? And yes, you do need to declare your own `operator =` and you have to do it properly (i.e. do a deep copy there as well). Search and read about **"The Rule of Three"** before proceeding.

Comment: And one more time: what "error" did you get? Give the full description of the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the operator like this:

```
Matrix operator* (const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: It's not the * operator buddy. It turned out to be the assignment operator. Thanks though.